# How do you construct a function that is continuous over $(0,1)$ whose image is the entire real line?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How do you construct a continuous function over the interval $(0,1)$ whose image is the entire real line?

When I first saw this problem, I thought $\frac{1}{x(x-1)}$ might work since it is continuous on $(0,1)$, but when I graphed it, I saw that there is a minimum at $(1/2,4)$, so the image is $[4,\infty)$ and not $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Apparently, one answer to this question is:

$$\frac{2x-1}{x(x-1)}$$

But how is one supposed to arrive at this answer without using a  graphing calculator?

Comment: Modify the tangent function

Comment: The question is "how do you construct a function?", not "gimme functions plz". Please answer the question, not answer the question that the question is asking about.

Comment: You're wrong about your function's values. $1/x(x-1)$ is always negative and so can't have a minimum at $4$ notice that $x$ is positive and $x-1$ is negative on your interval. The value at $1/2$ is $-1$.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hopefully you agree that you want functions with vertical asymptotes at $0$ and $1$, which is why you wanted to try $\frac{1}{x(x-1)}$. The problem with it is that, on the interval $(0,1)$, it goes to $-\infty$ both near $0$ and near $1$ (the easiest calculator-free way to notice this is to note that it is always negative).

How can we fix this problem? By multiplying by a continuous function which is positive near $1$ (so the product still goes to $-\infty$ near $1$) and negative near $0$ (so it goes to $+\infty$ near $0$). One simple function like this is $2x-1$.

Answer (score 13):

I'd like to provide a different flavor of function. For $x \in (0,1)$

$$f(x) = \tan\bigg(\pi x-\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)$$

---

**EDIT**: How we get to above result?

We start with $\tan(x)$, which is continuous over $x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ whose image is the entire real line.

We want $x$ to be $(0,1)$ instead. So one easy way is we find a linear transformation (thus is continuous) of $x$ to transform $x$ from $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ to $(0,1)$.

Notice that if $\pi x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, then we have $x \in (-1/2, 1/2)$.

And if $(\pi x - \pi/2) \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, then we have $x\in (0,1)$, and that is what we want.

Answer (score 5):

You've come up with a function symmetric about $x=\frac{1}{2}$: it's an "even function" except that it's "even about $x=\frac{1}{2}$" rather than about $x=0$.

Translate left by $\frac{1}{2}$; then you've made a bona fide even function ("even about $x=0$"). Now, to get a function which is "odd about $x=\frac{1}{2}$", just multiply the translated version by $x$ to get a bona fide odd function, and then translate back. That's what you've done (up to a factor of $2$).

Answer (score 5):

This is a common question, often about a continuous function mapping $(-1,1)$ onto $\mathbb{R}$. For *that* setup, I have long enjoyed the [**Inverse Hyperbolic Tangent**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicTangent.html), $\tanh^{-1}$, as a function that does exactly the trick. However, the interval you begin with here is instead $(0,1)$, so to use this function would require first mapping $(0,1) \rightarrow (-1,1)$, which can be done via $x \mapsto 2x-1$.

And so that gives yet another answer: $x \mapsto \tanh^{-1}(2x-1)$ maps $(0,1)$ onto $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

Howabout:

$${(2x - 1)}\over{x(x - 1)}$$

Or, look at tan and scale it a bit.

How to do it without a graphing calculator? Learn the shapes of various simple functions e.g. $x^2$, $x^3$ and $1/x$.  Look up even and odd functions that others have mentioned.  Learn what happens when you add and mutiply functions.  Learn how to scale and shift the functions.

I didn't use a graphing calculator and I guess that the other responders didn't either.

Comment: The OP knows this is an answer; they ask how one arrives at this answer.

Comment: At the time that I posted it, he didn't.

Comment: I added some suggestions on how to get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try $f(x) = {1 \over x} - {1 \over 1-x}$.

(Note that $f(x) = {2x -1\over x (x-1)}$.)

Here is the idea behind this approach:

In general, if $\phi:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} \phi(x) = \infty$ and $\phi$ is bounded on $[a,1)$
for any $a>0$ you can construct a suitable function by
$f(x) = \phi(x)-\phi(1-x)$.

Comment: I would prefer to write this as $\frac1x+\frac1{x-1}$, the sum of two terms with negative derivatives on their respective domains (I'm not sure I should call them "everywhere decreasing functions"), and with poles at $0$ and $1$, so clearly giving a sum decreasing on $(0,1)$ with range $\Bbb R$. +1

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: I thought about that, but decided on the above form since it has some 'symmetry' about $x={1 \over 2}$. I should have elaborated why...

Comment: The question is "How do I do this?" not "Can you give me an example?"

Comment: @DavidRicherby: My first comment explains how this is a very natural thing to do, and gives you guarantee of the desired result without much computation (moreover it is certain to be bijective $(0,1)\to\Bbb R$, which the approach in the (currently accepted) answer by Micah does not ensure).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The answer is supposed to answer the question, not the comments below it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: The question was 'how is one supposed to arrive...', which the above illustrates. The OP was wondering where the function $x \mapsto {2x-1 \over x(x-1)}$ came from which is why I wrote the above. The only other answer which addresses this specific question is Micah's.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I find it curious how quick folks are to jump on things in a negative way.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping in mind that (cumulative) distribution functions in statistics take the real line to the unit interval, inverse cdfs for variables defined over the whole real line are a rich and convenient source of these.

An example of this would be the $\log(\frac{x}{1-x})$, which is the inverse cdf for the standard [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution) (this particular one is sometimes called the *logit* function).

If you scroll to the bottom of the page at that link, you'll see a couple of dozen possibilities in the table at the bottom, mostly under "Continuous univariate supported on the whole real line". Some of those will not have convenient inverse cdfs, but a number of them do.

Once you have a few of them you can combine them with functions from the real line to the real line or the unit interval to the unit interval to get a very wide range of easily-obtained functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example. Take the continuous function $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\cos\frac{\pi}x.$$ For $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $f(\frac1{2n})=2n$ and $f(\frac1{2n+1})=-2n-1$, so $[-2n-1,2n]$ lies in the image of $f$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Therefore, the image of $f$ is $\mathbb R$.

This example has the further property that $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=-1\in\mathbb R$ exists. (So $f$ can be extended to yield a surjection from $(0,1]$ onto $\mathbb R$.)